# android runtime error unable to instansiate application. classnotfoundexception

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I've an app that uses the ZXing library. The java compiler was set to a certain level, i can't remember what, sorry. I tried to use a switch statement and eclipse complained of an incorrect compiler level. I clicked on quick fix and now Eclipse is giving the following error.

```
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.carefreegroup.NfcScannerApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.carefreegroup.NfcScannerApplication
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:529)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4532)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.carefreegroup.NfcScannerApplication
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:948)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:520)
11-21 16:38:56.090: E/AndroidRuntime(20001):    ... 11 more
```

my Appliction is called nfcscannerappliction and i seem to be getting ClassNotFoundException. Any ideas how i can get my app compiled again?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to check the manifest and make sure that it is still correct in there and the spelling is correct just in case something was changed during the "fix".

Comment: @codeMagic I've sorted it now, thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[solved]

I had to go into the build path and click on the java compiler button, the set the compiler compliance level back to 1.6. The project had to be re-built and runs fine now.

thanks